# Lettrine in a custom environment

Tags: environments, documentclass-writing, lettrine

I want to use the `lettrine`-package in my custom class in order to modify the first letter in a section. The usual way of doing it is

```
\lettrine{T}{est} of my text
```

The problem for me is that I do not want to have to write that every time I am opening the environment. Thus I am looking for a solution which generates the same result as above, but written as

```
\begin{Testenvironment}
    Test of my text
\end{Testenvironment}
```

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the full solution, but it works by 'ignoring' the mandatory parameter of the environment.

Since `LaTeX` expects mandatory parameters delimited by `{...}`, the usage of a parameter without `{...}` will just grab the first token:

For example

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]
\foo This is is a nice text
```

will just grab the first character here, i.e. `T` and assumes this to be the argument, which is what the O.P. wants to achieve.

However, `\foo \something` will not work!

Colour settings etc. have to used as indicated in the `lettrine` manual, so `\foo \textcolor{red}{T}` won't work neither here!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newenvironment{Testenvironment}[2][]{%
  \lettrine[#1]{#2}{}%
}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{Testenvironment}
  Test of my text which is not very long at the moment but it seems to work at least for easy texts. 
\end{Testenvironment}

\begin{Testenvironment}[findent=10pt]
  {\textcolor{red}{T}}his another example
\end{Testenvironment}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solution is different from my approach, but I will test it. Thanks! Btw., is there also a solution for a construct like `\A Text words`, where `\A` is ignored, and `Text` will be taken instead (i.e. all things which are commands are ignored)?

Comment: @arc_lupus: I suspect, that an unexpandable command will not be used in the `\lettrine` command, but it won't skip to the next thing automatically. That requires more work

Comment: `\A Text` is not working, but `T\A ext` is working, by achieving nearly exactly the same result as I want, thus I think preliminary your solution will be used. Thanks!

Comment: @arc_lupus: Yes, but that's how TeX is designed: It grabs `T` (in my answer) as first token and ignores `\A` then (which enters then the body of the environment as expected)